# In a camera application, understanding how to build a layout containing the live camera preview

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

In the [Android Developer Guide about developing a Camera application](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera), after demonstrating how to create a camera preview class, they are demonstrating how to build a basic XML layout containing the camera preview.

In the [section titled "Placing preview in a layout"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera), it is stated

> This layout type is used so that additional picture information or
>   controls can be overlayed on the live camera preview images.

The question is

1. What kind of additional picture information are they talking about?
2. What do they mean by *overlaying* that additional picture information or *controls* in live camera preview *images*? and what controls are they talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Additional picture information

**Current camera status or the information you want to show.**

ex: Picture size(resolution), picture ratio, picture taken count, etc..

---

### Additional controls

**Change the camera setting or custom actions.**

ex: Switch picture size, flash light on/off, add a filter, etc..